# How to find the documentation of the python package SDF?

Tags: python, sdf

When I was reading some source codes by my tutor, I found such code:

```
a=sdf.read('.Data/0000.sdf')
```

Does SDF package have the method 'read'? And how can I find the documentation of the python package SDF?
Thanks.

Comment: If it is correctly installed, it should have installed its documentation, too. In the Python REPL, try `import sdf` followed by `help(sdf)`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-Python

From there:

> Read the dataset from the SDF file asserting the correct unit of the
> dataset and scale:

```
ds_v2 = sdf.load('sine.sdf', '/v', unit='V', scale_units=['s'])
```

Comment: Do you know for a fact that this is the package the OP is asking about? I can find several different Python SDF packages in PyPI.

Comment: I m in fact not sure it is the one he is asking about, but this one is maintained by Dassault Systèmes.